# Jupyter notebook on github : Hiding file paths

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook

I did not think this would be a big issue, as i think many data scientist have the issue, but I did not find a solution by googling for my problem:
I have a Jupyter Notebook (JN) for which I created a Github repository. In the JN I defined a path variable, like this:

```
data = 'folder/subfolder/datafile.csv'
```

How can I avoid showing this file path? Is there an easy way?
Maybe I did not google with the correct terms?

Every help is very appreciated!

Comment: You can hide cells from being displayed, see documentation here: https://jupyterbook.org/interactive/hiding.html
You could also try setting the path as an environment variable but I'm not sure if there are any implications with that approach.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and the idea with hiding cells, have not heard about it! However, I think I like the approach with setting environment variables. Do you know how to set them?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your operating system. This [link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/machine-learning/oml4r/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html#GUID-DD6F9982-60D5-48F6-8270-A27EC53807D0) shows how to do it on Windows. And this [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106778/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-on-os-x) shows how to set it up on a Mac.

Then your code would look something like this:

```
import os
path = os.environ.get('PATH')
```

Comment: Ah, okay, I'm on a Linux system, so I will try the approach from Mac. Thank you!